# Easy-to-use web portal software for sharing a collection of existing files

Tags: web-apps

Here's the problem.  A researcher has an existing large collection of files on a read-only file system that she wants to selectively share with a group of colleagues.

- She needs a system with a web-based UI
- She needs to be able to create and manage accounts for her colleagues
- She needs to be able to grant access to certain files, directories or subtrees of the collection to certain people / groups of people
- Users need to be able to browse the files they have access to, and select and download files, individually or as archives (e.g. ZIP files)
- Before downloading, the user needs to be presented with an "agree to terms" dialog ... potentially depending on what they are downloading
- She needs to be able to audit what files have been downloaded by whom, and when.

The software needs to be open source with no closed-source dependencies, and it needs to run on Linux.

The software could be a free standing web application, or a plugin / component of a larger framework ... provided that we can "turn off" functionality that is not relevant to the researcher's use-case.

**UPDATE**

Suggestions that meet "most" of the requirements are also welcome.

Comment: Wow. I was going to mention FileZilla with a Linux backend and tell you to have her set the permissions appropriately and what not, but it does not have a web interface, nor do I know of a way to force an "agree to terms" dialog. You might end up writing some code for this one.

Comment: There's lot of things that will do *some* of this but to get all of it I'm going to be say with a pretty high certainty that she'll need some custom solution. If a programatic solution would be of interest I could give some pointers.

Comment: @NickWilde - something that hits a significant subset of the requirements would be welcome.  If there is an existing solution that is close enough, we can either implement the rest ourselves or see if the requirements could be waived.  (In terms of implementing this from scratch, we *could* do it ourselves, if we had the time.)

Comment: yeah anything can be done with sufficient time. I'll think a bit on a few of my initial ideas and write up a answer that matches as close as possible with at least basic suggestions to meeting the rest.